# Huggingface sagemaker

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to use the **text2text** (translation) model [facebook/m2m100_418M](https://huggingface.co/facebook/m2m100_418M) to run on sagemaker.

So if you click on deploy and then sagemaker there is some boilerplate code that works well but I can't seem to find how to pass it the arguments `src_lang="en", tgt_lang="fr"` just like when using the pipeline or transformers.
So right now it translates into random languages.

I'm guessing I should add it in here somehow but it's not documented.

```
predictor.predict({
    'inputs': "The answer to the universe is"
})
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to pass arguments to the predict method?

**Edit**

This is the code that was wrong where you will need to change the HF_TASK:

````
import sagemaker

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'facebook/m2m100_418M',
    'HF_TASK':'text2text-generation'
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    transformers_version='4.6.1',
    pytorch_version='1.7.1',
    py_version='py36',
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge' # ec2 instance type
)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.
The task was wrong, the source and target language need to be in the task (HF_TASK)

So for example:
`'HF_TASK': 'translation_en_to_fr'`

Answer (score 0):

In general with Huggingface models the way to pass extra arguments is with a `parameters` dictionary. In this case:

```
predictor.predict({'inputs': "The answer to the universe is",
                   'parameters': {'src_lang': 'en', 'tgt_lang' : 'de'}})

# output: [{'translation_text': 'Die Antwort auf das Universum ist'}]
```

Comment: I already tried that and got this error

```botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "forward() got an unexpected keyword argument \u0027src_lang\u0027"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, interesting. Can you confirm this is the code you use for deployment?

```
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel
import sagemaker

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'facebook/m2m100_418M',
    'HF_TASK':'translation'
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    transformers_version='4.6.1',
    pytorch_version='1.7.1',
    py_version='py36',
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge' # ec2 instance type
)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly the same except for the HF_TASK I have ```text2text-generation``` and not```translate```